# setting cache size in davs via nautilus

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I'd like to increase my client cache size when connecting to a davs:// share via Nautilus with connect server and then davs://user@address/dav.

I used to use davfs2 that came with a config while where cache size and location could be defined.

I don't have davfs2 installed and I'm wondering where Nautilus is getting the davs config from?

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine you will find the answer here:

```
man davfs2.conf
```

Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately that conf file seems to be ignored by nautilus. Actually, I can davs:.. via nautilus without having davfs2 installed at all.

Comment: not the behaviour the man states. "There  is  a  system wide configuration file /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf and user configuration files ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf. ...."  This does imply nautilus can not get an other control info.  If you say "I don't have davfs2 installed " it clearly uses defaults. May be you install it properly to get the config files back in control? Then you may just define your needs in one of the specified config files. Just a guess.